# Can part of an AppleWatch interface scroll independently?

Tags: ios, scroll, watchkit, wkinterfacegroup

I've got a WatchKit app that consists of a label and a couple of buttons. The label's contents might be long enough to cause scrolling, but I want the buttons to stay onscreen. Is it possible to have the label content scroll instead of the whole screen?

I've tried embedding the label in a `WKInterfaceGroup`, but the height of the label gets constrained to the height of the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also tried to find a way to do this, but I couldn't find anything.  Based on the simple flow layout for a Watch App UI I am pretty sure this can't be done.

(I am going to guess I was trying to do the same/similar UI as you ;)

Comment: Yes, we are creating a maps feature for the Watch in Bible+ ;-)

Comment: I was trying to get this UI to work for the ESV Bible and I also thought about using it for zoom on the map.